# Detect page change on DataTable

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

With [DataTable](http://datatables.net/) I can order, list, do pagination but I want to detect when the pagination changes, I've seen the [API](http://datatables.net/api) but the only one I can do is change the page but no detect this change.

Comment: Is there a specific reason behind detecting the page change?

Comment: Yes, I want to send to the server what pages has been viewed by the user.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You may use [fnDrawCallback](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnDrawCallback) or [fnInfoCallback](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnInfoCallback) to detect changes, when **next** is clicked both of them are fired.

But beware, page changes are not the only source that can fire those callbacks.

#### For DataTables 1.10.0+

The option is now [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback)

Comment: THis is the only solution that worked, but as he mentioned these events are triggered on many other things including fnAddData.

Comment: this answer is outdated, see answers below for newer versions

Comment: With page.dt event, you handle it before the page change. if you put your code in the fnDrawCallback, It will execute after the page change.

Answer (score 46):

Paging events are handled in this way,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  
    $('#example')
        .on( 'order.dt',  function () { console.log('Order' ); } )
        .on( 'search.dt', function () {console.log('Search' ); } )
        .on( 'page.dt',   function () { console.log('Page' ); } )
        .dataTable();
} );
```

documented in the official website, here http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dt_events.html

The length.dt event is fired whenever the table's page length is changed

```
$('#example').dataTable();
 
$('#example').on( 'length.dt', function ( e, settings, len ) {
    console.log( 'New page length: '+len );
} );
```

http://datatables.net/reference/event/length

More events here

http://datatables.net/reference/event/

Comment: Thanks! Im used `.on( 'page.dt',   function () { console.log('Page' ); } )` very well!

Comment: When i used `$('#example').on( 'page.dt',   function () { mySpecificFunction(); } )` it is only calling my function, it does not changing the page. even my function works  without any error.

Answer (score 33):

I got it working using:

```
$('#id-of-table').on('draw.dt', function() {
    // do action here
});
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how this code answers the question. This will help the OP and other future searchers of this question.

Comment: Idk what more to say, as it's per documentation of DataTables

Comment: This solution works perfectly for me. For more information on the event "draw.dt", please visit [link](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw).

Comment: This worked for me because this is called *after* the new page rows are inserted. Using page.dt was called after the pagination button was clicked but before it replaces the new rows in the table.

Comment: That's awsome. Works great for me.

Comment: This working perfect for me! As the page.dt event is before the new page is finished loading, but with this one is executes my code after the new page loading is finsihed.

Answer (score 20):

IF you have a version greater than 1.8, you can use this to hit the page change events:

```
    $('#myTable').on('page', function () {...} );
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

Some comments have pointed out that using .live() instead of .on() worked for them. Be aware of that you should try both and see which one works best in your particular circumstance! (I believe this may have to do with your version on jQuery, but please comment if you find another reason!)

Comment: Small update to your solution. The .on() method did not work for me. I changed it to .live() and it worked great.

Comment: I think the .live() v. .on() may deal with your version on jQuery / DT. I've been using .on() and it works for me. @ScottBeeson, what is your specific issue? If you're going to vote down my answer, please at least provide an example that proves it is not working in your particular circumstance. It seems to work for others and myself.

Comment: I'm wondering how to trigger the same function when the first page is loaded.

Comment: Since datatables 1.10 you need namespacing --> http://next.datatables.net/manual/events.

Answer (score 12):

```
$('#tableId').on('draw.dt', function() {
    //This will get called when data table data gets redrawn to the      table.
});
```

Comment: Apart from the different comment, I don't see how this is different from Alvin's answer..

Answer (score 11):

In my case, the 'page.dt' event did not do the trick.

I used 'draw.dt' event instead, and it works!, some code:

```
$(document).on('draw.dt', function () {
    //Do something
});
```

'Draw.dt' event is fired everytime the datatable page change by searching, ordering or page changing.

/***** Aditional Info *****/

There are some diferences in the way we can declare the event listener. You can asign it to the 'document' or to a 'html object'. The 'document'  listeners will always exist in the page and the 'html object' listener will exist only if the object exist in the DOM in the moment of the declaration. Some code:

//Document event listener

```
$(document).on('draw.dt', function () {
    //This will also work with objects loaded by ajax calls
});
```

//HTML object event listener

```
$("#some-id").on('draw.dt', function () {
    //This will work with existing objects only
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This working good

```
$('#id-of-table').on('draw.dt', function() {
    // do action here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach would be to register an event handler on the pagination link like so:

```
$("#dataTableID_paginate").on("click", "a", function() { alert("clicked") });
```

Replace "#dataTableID_" with the ID of your table, of course. And I'm using JQuery's ON method as that is the current best practice.

Comment: more specifically, `$('#myTableId_wrapper').find('.dataTables_paginate').on('click', 'li:not(.disabled) a', function() {`

Answer (score 2):

Try using delegate instead of live as here:

```
$('#link-wrapper').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
  // do something ..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works form me to scroll to when I click next

```
$('#myTable').on('draw.dt', function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

If you handle the draw.dt event after page.dt, you can detect exactly after moving the page. After work, draw.dt must be unbind

```
    $(document).on("page.dt", () => {
        $(document).on("draw.dt", changePage);
    });

    const changePage = () => {
        // TODO
        $(document).unbind("draw.dt", changePage);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I've not found anything in the API, but one thing you could do is attach an event handler to the standard paginator and detect if it has changed:

```
$('.dataTables_length select').live('change', function(){
       alert(this.value);
    });
```