# Datatables page change callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using a function 'fnDrawCallback' for page change. It basically solves my purpose. The only thing is I have to specify that function when I am initializing dataTable object. Is there any way I can do it after initialization?

For Example:
I am doing like this:

```
$("#tableID").dataTables({'fnDrawCallBack':functionName});
```

I want to do like this:

```
var oTable = $("#tableID").dataTables();
oTable.fnDrawCallback = functionName;    // or something like this
```

Solution:

```
oTable.aoDrawCallback.push(functionObj);
var functionObj = {
   fn: funtionName
};
```

Comment: I want to know is there a way I can specify that function after initializing dataTable object.

Comment: Can I specify AJAX pageLoad event after initialization??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407111/detect-page-change-on-datatable

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could access the internal data settings of DataTables to manipulate the draw callback array (aoDrawCallback, not fnDrawCallback internally - its an array since there can be multiple callbacks), or (and what I would suggest) you can add a 'draw' event listener:

```
var oTable = $("#tableID").dataTables();
$(oTable).bind( 'draw', functionName );
```

The events fired by DataTables are documented here: http://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.0/#summary_events

Comment: Binding events is not working in the version of dataTables I am using. But thank you for a good suggestion.

Comment: aoDrawCallback worked for me. I have to push an object in that array and your function should be a fn property of that function.

Comment: Binding events $(oTable).bind() does seem to work with the newer versions 1.9.2+.

Comment: This is wrong, you want to bind to 'page' not 'draw'.  See my answer below for something working on the current (1.9.4) version.

Comment: @ScottRFrost why is it wrong to bind to `draw` rather than `page`? From what I can tell, in 1.9.4 they both fire in exactly the same circumstances (i.e. upon page change but _not_ when the table is initially generated). The distinction is that `draw` fires **after** the table has been drawn, thus allowing for code that manipulates the just-drawn rows (e.g. binding event handlers) — `page` fires  **before** the rows are drawn. Either can be more appropriate depending on the functionality required.

Comment: @RyanWilliams.  draw is fired EVERY TIME the grid is redrawn, not just on paging events. Lots of other things will fire draw, so hooking a function there doesn't fit what OP was asking for.

Answer (score 6):

IF you have a version greater than 1.8, you can use this to hit the page change events:

```
    $('#myTable').on('page', function () {...} );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my case, I used "page.dt" but this only works on my third page for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You probably saw this
http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2737/addchange-callback-after-initialization-or-else-clone-settings-to-re-build-table/p1

Comment: This seems to work for people but they added "bRetrieve" in later versions. I have 1.6.2 version and they don't have bRetrieve in that.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than two separate calls, just add a .bind() prior to the .dataTable(), such as the following that runs a setMouseDown function whenever a page change occurs (including rendering the first page):

```
$('#myTable')
    .bind('page', setMouseDown())
    .dataTable( 
    { 
        bJQueryUI: true, 
        ... Other Init Stuff Here ... 
    });
```